# is it possible to insert custom adds into AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I'm developing an app and I wanted to upload custom video adds into my app that let user to get rewarded when they watch the video. is this possible? and is there an API for this?

Comment: You don't need to AdMob specifically to show your video as a rewarded ad, you can use ExoPlayer & use the relevant event listeners to determine the playback state.

Comment: @DarShan I know I can do that but that will make the app to be tied to the video. what I wanted is to upload video that I wanted to advertise and google will handle whether the user has fully finished watching the ad

Comment: You can use a backend to his a Json file with appropriate parameters & video links which will show the videos from specified links. You'll have to implement the parsing & the model creation though.